# Creating a trigger that updates "total_price" object each time transaction table is modified

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a simple web_shop database for a university project, it needs to store users past orders and display total costs of orders. I've been trying to fix this problem for a few hours

With the current triggers I have in place, when I try to insert any more rows into my 'transaction' table I get the error:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

and the 'total price' for each receipt/order is shown as '17.9' (they should be 17.9 for receipt_id '1' and 3.5 for receipt_id '2'). A receipt is a group of transactions (*eg receipt_id = 5 -> 5 oranges, 3 bananas and 1 apple total price of $12.50*)

sub_total(transaction) is calculated (price of item * quantity) through the following (3) triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER calcsub_insert BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE/AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.sub_total = NEW.transaction_price * NEW. transaction_quantity;
END
```

total_price(receipt) is currently calculated through the following (3) triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE/AFTER DELETE ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE receipt
    SET total_price = (SELECT SUM(sub_total) FROM transactions GROUP BY receipt_id)
```

I've included my schema below to hopefully make the situation a bit clearer. I thought 'group by' would return all the totals for each receipt_id but it doesnt seem to work. Thanks for any help or tips in advance!

[webshop db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHmfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT ... GROUP BY receipt_id` query will return a row for each distinct value of `receipt_id`.

Maybe we only want to return a row for a single value of `receipt_id`. The value from the `transactions` row that fired the trigger.

```
 SELECT SUM(t.sub_total) FROM transaction t WHERE t.receipt_id = NEW.receipt_id
```

and seems like we only want to update the row(s) in `receipt` with a matching `receipt_id`

```
 UPDATE receipt r 
    ... 
  WHERE r.receipt_id = NEW.receipt_id
```

---

(Is the name of the table `transactions` (referenced in the trigger definition) supposed to be the same as the name of the table `transaction` referenced in the SELECT query? Right now, it's a bit confusing, because it looks like those are referencing two different tables.)

---

The timing for the triggers seems a bit odd... calculating a total from `transactions` right *before* a new row is added to `transactions`, instead of getting the total updated *after* a change is applied. Also seems like we want to make sure the value for `sub_total` is assigned before we refer to it. (Now that MySQL 5.7 allows for multiple BEFORE INSERT triggers on a table, if we are going to have multiple triggers, we need to take care what order the triggers get fired in if there's a dependency.

(Then again, I don't have an understanding of the use case.)

Also an edge case to consider... an UPDATE of `transactions` that modifies `receipt_id`... seems like there would be might be two values of receipt_id that could be affected. Consider this UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `transactions` t
   SET t.receipt_id = 3333
 WHERE t.receipt_id = 2222
   AND t.transaction_id = 111
```

Seems like we would want to update two rows in `receipt` table... one with `r.receipt_id = OLD.receipt_id` and one with `r.receipt_id = NEW.receipt_id`.

When `OLD.receipt_id = NEW.receipt_id`, we would only have one row to update. We only need to update two rows when `NEW.receipt_id <> OLD.receipt_id`.

Comment: _Is the name of the table transactions (referenced in the trigger definition) supposed to be the same... ?_ - no sorry updated both to "transactions".

So i want to remove the BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers and replace with AFTER INSERT/UPDATE that goes:

UPDATE receipt
    SET total_price = (SELECT SUM(sub_total) FROM transactions GROUP BY receipt_id)
WHERE r.receipt_id = NEW.receipt_id

_(the use case.)_ - The only interaction with the database is basic insert rows via PHP that will INSERT new customers, products, transactions and create new "receipts".